# Can't find certain function when calling R within java

Tags: java, r, processing, rserve

I'm trying to use R within Java, specifically within Processing.
I want to use the `readPNG` function, but when I try to, R displays an error `readPNG function can't be found`. This is extremely weird because I have the `png library` active and if I try to use it directly from R this workouts just fine. I'm using the `Rserve`package to connect java and R. Any advise would be very much appriciated.
Here's part of the code I'm using if it helps.

```
import org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.*;
import org.rosuda.REngine.*;

double[] data;

void setup() {
  size(300,300);
  try {
    RConnection c = new RConnection();  
    // generate 100 normal distributed random numbers and then sort them 
    data= c.eval("readPNG('juego-11932.png')").asDoubles();

  } catch ( REXPMismatchException rme ) {
    rme.printStackTrace();

  } catch ( REngineException ree ) {
    ree.printStackTrace();
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  for( int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    line( i * 3.0, height/2, i* 3.0, height/2 - (float)data[i] * 50 );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever load the png package?

Comment: In Rstudio it's loaded but I don't do a `library(png)`or similar command inside processing.

Comment: The R session your java script uses and the one you have opened via RStudio are most likely distinct. Try loading the package from within your script. Maybe `data= c.eval("{library(png); readPNG('juego-11932.png')}").asDoubles()`?

Comment: Thanks! that helped, but not entirely. I also had to specify the
location of my file `juego-11932.png`by setting my working directory to the proper direction using `setwd()`.
This is just in case someone reads this question and finds it usefull!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Java code connects to a fresh R session so no packages are loaded. Hence you have to either use `png::readPNG()` or load the `png` package explicitly.